# Adding prefix to all css classes

Tags: css, class, prefix

I am doing a project and i am instructed to add prefix to each classes of css. How would i go for this adding prefixes to all class using a text editor. I am using Sublime text editor.
e.g .someclass{
}
TO 
.za_someclass{
}

Comment: In your text editor just replace ' .' with ' .za_' :)

Comment: Wanted to do this at first but it seems to do the same for numerical values for 2.5em and so on, anyway there r not much numericals so can delete the za_ from numericals manually....Thanks...

Comment: that is why you need the space before the .

Answer (score 0):

Anyway tried going through all the regex commands again and found the solution for it. Use ^.\b Where^(Match the beginning of the string).(will take the dot at the begining of the line) and \b(Match the beginning or end of a word) So excluding the numericals like 5.6em/pt etc from the css. Further using .za_ in my case to replace/prefix all instances.